# Unable to fix dirty bit on EFI partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, fsck

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer in dual boot with Windows 10. After having installed it, each time I boot Ubuntu a file system check is performed. It seems that there is a problem with the EFI partition. This is the output of `fsck`

```
sck da util-linux 2.34
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 2
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
? 3
/dev/sda2: 202 files, 33670/98304 clusters
```

If I remove the dirty bit, after rebooting I have the same problem. These are the specs of my computer:

- MB: ASRock H270 Pro4
- Processor: i5 7600
- HD: 1 TB WD Blue (`/home` and swap partition, data partition for windows)
- SSD: 500 GB Crucial (`/`, Windows, EFI and Recovery partition)
- NVidia GTX 950

I have disabled secure boot and fast boot.